# Adjoint of a translation operator

Tags: operator-theory

Could you explain, what the adjoint operator of the translation operator $T_n$ is and why so?

$$
\{T_ng(x)\}_{n\in Z} = \{g(x-n)\}_{n\in Z} \\
\langle T_kg, T_lg \rangle = \langle g, T_{l-k}g \rangle
$$

Regarding spaces $\{T_ng(x)\}_{n\in Z} \in l^2$ and $g(x) \in L^2$.

Comment: What space is this?

Comment: If the space is $l^2$ then $T_n$ is unitary so the adjoint is equal to the inverse $T_{-n}$.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler Would you mind to elaborate, why it's unitary?

Comment: Because $\langle T_n x, T_n y \rangle = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x(k-n) y(k-n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x(k) y(k) = \langle x, y \rangle.$

Comment: Or of course, if the scalar field is $\mathbb{C}$, then put conjugates over the $x$ terms in the middle two sums.